# jQuery: Smooth scrolling "back to top" within a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know there are a ton of jQuery "back to top" questions on Stack Overflow, but I haven't come across a solution that would work for this problem:

I have a list inside a div which will be a variable height (the list will get much longer as I gradually update the website). So I would like use a "back to top" button to scroll the div to the top. Most "back to top" scripts that I've come across control the scrolling of the body tag and not divs.

I've tried a few different approaches that I found on this site, but I'm completely stumped. Attached is a JSFiddle of my code which controls the body instead of the div.

PS. I'm using a webkit scrollbar to show scrolling on the div.

Thanks in advance :-)

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
    $('#toTop').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('#toTop').fadeOut();
  }
});

$("#toTop").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.menu {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 478px;
}
#toTop {
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item

</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id='toTop'>Back to top.</div>
```

Comment: `$(".menu").animate(...);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your element in the scrolltop script instead of html,body

```
$("#toTop").click(function() {
  $("#myscrollingelement").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1000);
});
```

Here is it in relation to your sample code:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  /* irrelevant to question
  if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
    $('#toTop').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('#toTop').fadeOut();
  }
  */
});

$('#toTop').fadeIn()
.click(function() {
  $(".menu").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1000);
  /* if you want the body to scroll to the top AS WELL
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1000);
  */
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.menu {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 478px;
}
#toTop {
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Menu item

</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id='toTop'>Back to top.</div>
```

Comment: This code works great. I thought I'd tried swapping out body with the id, but couldn't get it to work.

How could I then make the button fade in after scrolling?

Comment: At what point after scrolling to you want the button to fade in? Do you want it to come in after scrolling a certain amout of pixels or after you reach a certain element?

Comment: I think it would make sense in this case to base the fade in on pixels, in case I change the element at a certain point. How would you fade it in based on a pixel count?

Comment: That should be a separate question; one I am sure is already answered on StackOverflow

Comment: @S.Kiers is right this should probably be its own question but check out the following fiddle and read the comments that I have in the javascript section.  It will show you how to fade in the button several different ways  https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/3wcw75ww/

Comment: Thanks for uploading the code and explaining it to me. It doesn't seem to work for me in your jsfiddle though. Seems that the "Back to top." is always invisible. Any ideas?

Comment: It is working just fine.  The code that is in place requires you to scroll 50px before it will fade in.  Make sure you resize the window so that you are able to scroll the 50 px or change the code to scroll a smaller number of px

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right. I just had to change this:

$(window).scroll(function() {

to the div:

$(".main").scroll(function() {